# In Django project, Python says Pillow is not installed but it is installed

Tags: python, django, pycharm, windows-10, python-3.9

After upgrading Python 3.8 to 3.9 this error has happened and says pillow is not installed. I tried to uninstall and reinstall pillow, but it did not worked.

I'm using Django 3.1 on a Windows 10 pro.

The output of `pip freeze` is attached too.

Here is the error message:

```
ERRORS:

magazine.Magazine.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
post.Posts.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
post.Sample.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
post.Workers.avatar: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
product.Products.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you run django? And please add all textual information as text, not as an image!

Comment: Activate the venv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's warning because old version of pip was renaming folders that it could not delete, replacing first letter with tilda ~.

In your `C:\..\python38-32\lib\site-packages` have a folder named `~illow...`.

When I delete that folder and reinstall `python -m pip Pillow`, it's worked.

I have same error and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552380/pip3-warning-could-not-generate-requirement-for-distribution-ertifi-2019-11) solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Activate the virtual environment (your env path).\Scripts\activate
2.Run the Django application

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any Pillow or PIL folder (older version) in your main project directory, as this will cause conflicts if you have Pillow installed in a virtual environment or in the PythonXX folder.

If you are using the virtual environment, you will need to re-install pillow. But do not run "pip uninstall Pillow" before you activate the virtual environment.

Remove any older versions of Pillow if you had manually put them in your project folder. Activate the virtual environment, *then* uninstall, and then install it again.

```
env/Scripts/activate.ps1

pip uninstall Pillow

python -m pip install Pillow
```